# Adding vertex without moving cursor

Tags: qgis, vertices

I am trying to add a vertex to a shape without moving the cursor. Using the vertex tool, I double left-click on the line and then left-click a third time. If it is a temporary scratch file, it works fine, and the vertex appears on the line without moving the cursor or line. However, if I make the shapefile permanent, it doesn't work anymore. After I double click on the line, I have to move the cursor to create the vertex. Of course, this causes the line to move, and I have to move the newly created vertex back so the line is in the approximate location of where it was before. The behavior is the same for both lines and polygons.

This seems very strange behavior to me. Is there some setting that I need to change for it to work with permanent shapefiles?

I am using QGIS 3.16.7.

Comment: SHIFT + Double Left Click will insert vertices without moving the line.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. For a while, it didn't work every time, until I figured out that I needed to increase the snapping tolerance some from the default 12px.